# Reptiles and Humans co-existing in high oxygenated world?

Tags: biology, planets

I'm world building a planet dominated by reptiles (they are around the size of dogs) for a sci-fi story of mine. I figure that in order to have larger reptiles, I'll need the planet to have a higher oxygen content. However, humans also live in this world, and I was wondering if this is still physiologically plausible? I've read a bit on oxygen toxicity, but I'm not sure about the exact oxygen amount I should have, or get away with.

Comment: Don't we already live on a world with humans and dog size reptiles?  A 2200lb [(salt-water crocodile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_reptiles) could eat a pack of dogs as a light lunch.

Comment: Higher oxygen partial pressure wouldn't help reptiles much. What mammals have and reptiles don't is homethermy, that is, the ability to keep the temperature inside their bodies constant. Reptiles are poikilothermic animals, a.k.a. cold blooded, which means that they don't have the ability to regulate their internal temperature. In cold weather, they are sluggish or cannot move at all. If it's too hot they overheat and die unless they can find shadow. If they do a lot of effort they overheat and must stop or die, so their endurance is much lower than the endurance of mammals.

Comment: I don't see what's your actual problem, given that you basically described our own planet.

Comment: Insects, not reptiles, are the ones that (maybe) grow huge in high oxygen environments.

Comment: I think you'll find that other environmental factors dominate mere atmospheric oxygen content.  I agree with RonJohn though.  High oxygen content will benefit insects far more than reptiles.

Comment: But, the question is a bit unclear what you're looking for.  Do you want oxygen content quotes or factors that would lead to large reptiles?

Answer (score 5):

Yes totally possible. Like 100%. For instance alligators and crocodiles are both wayyy bigger than dogs and breathe our atmosphere and are fine.

Besides more oxygen isn't really a requirement for reptiles since they do have lungs and everything its much more a requirement for insects arachnids excetra who have to rely on diffusion through spiricals. The main limiting factors for reptiles is heat since they can't control it themselves.

Alternativly if you do have additional oxygen your humans would have just evolved to be more resistant to oxygen poisoning or have a very blueberry heavy diet. Its worth noting that humans can live in partial pressures of oxygen half that at sea-level I imagine that it probably has a similar tolerance the other way too.

Comment: Weirdly healthy humans can apparently breath pure oxygen, at sea-level or lower pressures, for extended periods without ill-effect it's only when the partial pressure goes up over 1.6 Bar that it starts to cause issues.

Comment: In other words, the humans would eat a bunch of antioxidant-heavy foods to get rid of those oxygen radicals.

Comment: Yup, though I don't think it'd be all that necessary tbh

Comment: I thought the scientific verdict was till out on dietary antioxidants?

Answer (score 2):

Higher levels of atmospheric oxygen may actually impend the success of reptiles, if it's at the expense of greenhouse gases, remember reptiles *by definition* cannot regulate their body temperature internally. A world with very little Carbon Dioxide, or Methane, in the atmosphere will be much cooler, given the same [insolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_irradiance), than one with a good thick atmosphere high in Carbon Dioxide. So you really **don't** need more oxygen to have big reptiles, depending on the habitat range, in terms of latitude, that you want reptiles to be prevalent in you might actually want to reduce the relative level of oxygen, particularly as [Ozone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozone) in your planetary atmosphere.

Comment: But during the eras when dinosaurs and large insects roamed the earth, it was both more tropical in climate AND the oxygen content was higher, right? Just wondering.

Comment: @aniben Nope, those were two different [Periods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Period_(geology)) (actually the age of the dinosaurs spanned several periods) during different [Eras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Era_(geology)) Dinosaurs were around for the  whole [Mesozoic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesozoic) while giant insects and arachnids are only seen in the fossils for the [Carboniferous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carboniferous) about 100 million years earlier.

Comment: This is the most important point.  Dinosaurs were (very likely) driven to extinction by an asteroid, but neither that nor climate is the reason why reptiles no longer evolve to become huge.  As I understand it, reptiles stopped getting big because mammals started filling all of the big animal niches.

Comment: @PinkSweetener Dinosaurs probably weren't reptiles, or even [ectotherms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ectotherm) so reptiles in the Mesozoic and the modern [Quaternary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternary) were/are reasonably similar in size, although bigger prey meant some groups could be, and were, much larger, like crocodiles.

Comment: @Ash I was under the impression that there was still a lively debate in the scientific community regarding whether or not dinosaurs are endo/ectotherms.  My general point was just that very large scaley creatures have come and gone throughout the epochs, but the reason they have not returned during our time probably has more to do with the arrival of mammals rather than atmospheric changes.  Crocodiles, alligators, and monitors are all quite big, but they all occupy roughly the same niche - supporting the notion that the loss of large scaled animals (reptile or dinosaur) is niche-related.

Comment: @PinkSweetener I had the impression that there are still several people who are very vocal about saying dinosaurs are cold-blooded who get ignored by the majority of the scientific community but still get into the popular press. Yes it has nothing to do with the atmosphere but humans met things like _Varanus Priscus_ and _Quinkana_ so truly giant reptiles do still have natural niches in the modern era but since humans don't tolerate large predators where we can eliminate them, whether they're reptiles or mammals, we've wiped out the really big reptiles because they were all carnivorous.